# Exceptions C++ show a variable in the error message

Tags: c++, qt, exception, pointers

In my Qt project, I am handling multiple exceptions in this way:

myExceptions.h:

```
#ifndef MYEXCEPTIONS_H
#define MYEXCEPTIONS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class myExceptions : public runtime_error
{

public:
    myExceptions(const char *msg ) : runtime_error(msg){};
    ~myExceptions() throw(){};

};

#endif // MYEXCEPTIONS_H
```

I call an exception in my code in this way:

abc.cpp

```
if (!MyClass::aMethod(a, b) )
{
  throw myExceptions("Error message to show");

 }
```

and catch it in my main.cpp:

```
 try {
        MyClass2 myClass2(param);
    } catch (myExceptions &e) {
       QMessageBox::critical(&window, "title", e.what());
    }
```

No problem until here, but it occurs when I would like to show in the error message the name of a variable tmpName.

```
 std::string tmpName; 

 else{
     throw myExceptions("Unrecognized member : " + &tmpName);
 }
```

When I do this, I got the following error:

```
C2110:'+' : cannot add two pointers.
```

Can someone help me, please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&`: `throw myExceptions("Unrecognized member : " + tmpName);`

This way, you add a const char* and a std::string, instead of trying to add two const char*.

Comment: I think you mean "trying to add a `const char *` and a *pointer* to `std::string`"?

Comment: By doing so, I got this error:

C2440:  cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits._Ax>' to 'myExceptions'

Comment: Colet: if you declare the parameter `msg` in the `myExceptions` constructor to be of type `const std::string&`, then everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in below line

```
throw myExceptions("Unrecognized member : " + &tmpName);
```

You are trying to add const char * to address of tmpName string. 
You should do

```
 tmpName = "Unrecognized member : " + tmpName;
 throw myExceptions(tmpName.c_str());
```

Since your myException class takes `const char *` as a parameter